# Reading a table in cqlsh returns "unconfigured table" error even when the table exists

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to learn a bit about cassandra, and for this I placed a 3 node cassandra datacenter on a kubernetes we have. I've created everything from ground up, and I was doing some tests that I already did on my local environment... but it doesn't work for some reason. It's pretty basic, and if I connect via the command line, I use a keyspace that I defined earlier, and I do:

```
describe tables;
```

This shows me correctly all the tables I have created on my `test_1` keyspace:
[image: tables list]

But when a moment later I do:

```
select * from "RawBooking";
```

I'm hit with the message "unconfigured table RawBooking". (this is an example, but it's the same for all the tables in the list).

This is the result of the `nodetool describecluster` command:

```
Cluster Information:
    Name: guezzt
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
    DynamicEndPointSnitch: enabled
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
            eaf7f96e-8543-3064-a314-351367075ba3: [10.128.3.100, 10.130.2.103]

            c8fa5021-e1d4-3fec-ae5e-f7a9f0c042b9: [10.128.4.102]
```

What am I doing wrong? can you suggest me what I should look to better understand the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Were these tables created with CQLSH?  Or were these created from within (Java?) code?

Comment: If it's the latter, the cluster might be having issues with schema agreement.  Run a `nodetool describecluster` on one of the nodes and see how many schema versions are present.

Comment: Also, I'm really going to advocate hard here for using lowercase + snake case for table names.  When it comes to preserving camel case with double quotes, I'm going to channel Yoda from Star Wars and just say "only pain will you find."

Comment: @Aaron I created them using node.js library. Also, I've added the result of the command you told me, but I'm not sure what it means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the driver (embedded in cqlsh) returns the "Unconfigured table" error when there is a schema disagreement in the cluster.

If you programmatically made schema changes without checking and waiting for the schema to be propagated to all nodes in the cluster, then the nodes would have different versions of the schema which is what we refer to as "schema disagreement" -- nodes do not have the same schema version so they don't "agree".

When you run a query that hits a node with a different version of the schema, it doesn't know about the table you queried so returns the "unconfigured table" error.

You should perform a rolling restart, one node at a time starting with a seed node. This should resolve your issue. Cheers!

Comment: thank you, that seems to have solved the problem. It seems there was a problem of communication between a node and the other two, and once we solved it, we restarted all the nodes and it worked!